# JVM creation failed with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, teamviewer

I am experiencing a very strange and annoying issue with my PC.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit, and have netbeans installed. It worked like a charm, but about 2 or 3 months ago I started getting an error "JVM Creation failed" when trying to enter netbeans. After reinstalling netbeans and also downloading the latest Java version, it still occured, but found that when I exit Teamviewer I manage to get in. I figured it had to do with Teamviewer, but found that sometimes when my PC goes to sleep and I try to go into netbeans the same happens even with teamviewer closed. I literally have to then go and close all my apps before I get to go into Teamviewer.

I could reinstall Windows but it feels like it would be a waste as my machine is running perfectly. I have googled the issue but cannot find a similiar problem, anyone else have some ideas?

Comment: Please see, [SO: Netbeans 7: JVM Creation Failed, which settting to change in netbeans.conf (windows)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030724/netbeans-7-jvm-creation-failed-which-settting-to-change-in-netbeans-conf-wind)